For a UART communication, when do we enable/disable the peripheral wrt changing between transmitting and receiving mode?
I am working with SAML22 microcontroller and I am supposed to write the transmission code using the interrupt mode. I am confused in which case I am supposed to disable the peripheral.
When changing from RX to TX mode, am I supposed to disable the receiver.
The data sheet does not tells a lot about these sequences (or maybe I am too inexperienced to understand it).
Edit:
The system that I am working on has two MCUs, connected by a full-duplex UART link (TXD1-->RXD2, TXD2-->RXD1) for data exchange. There are a set of parameters that my MCU needs to send to the other MCU. The root cause of my confusion is my inexperience and the large code base that I am working on.

Can you be more specific what you are doing with the UART? 99% of cases don't require switching anything between receive and transmit but basically transmitting and receiving completely asynchronouly - unless you have a half duplex interface which you don't mention.

All UARTs I've ever seen in MCUs have two separate and independent sections: a transmitter and a receiver. They often share CPU registers but they operate totally independently from each other. You might have a board with electronics that then shares the MCU RXD and TXD pins up a single wire but we don't know. Please edit your question (don't add info in comments) and explain what circuitry you have on your board, how it's connected, what you're connected to and what protocol you're trying to follow. Thanks.

Generally, in your scenario, you just enable the UART for reception and transmission and if bytes come in then read them into some buffer for processing them (if you use intrrrupts) and if you need to transmit bytes then you can do so in any way possible with your MCU, like with a polled loop or using interrupts.
The used MCU does not change these basic principles, but simple MCUs may give you a bare UART you must handle with interrupts or by polling flags, fancier MCUs offer DMA transfers and FIFOs for reducing CPU overhead.

thanks for the answer. The current code that I am working on does the RX in interrupt mode and tx in polling mode. I am supposed to implement the TX in interrupt mode. The place where I am stuck is I cannot understand when I am supposed to enable the transmission (probably before I start sending the data) and when I am supposed to disable the TX interrupt.

@user23335133 That depends what options you have available and how you want to do it. Some UARTs give you a "TX empty" interrupt and/or "TX complete" interrupt. Either will do. If you have nothing to send, disable the interrupt so it does not happen. When you do have data to send, enable it, and you get interrupt when you can write next byte, if you have more bytes to send.

Or don't disable the interrupt, and the interrupt handler sets a flag in software.  So that next time you do want to transmit something, you already know that there's space available in the UART.

@user23335133 You normally don't need to actually disable tramsmit on a UART.  If it has no data to send, it just sends a stream of stop bits, which the receiver ignores.

@SimonB the interrupts need to be disabled or you get constant interrupts about TX buffer being empty so it does not consume 100% of CPU time. The TX side itself does not need disabling. And if UART does not have any data to send, it certainly does not send a stream of stop bits, the line will idle high (although it is the same state than stop bit but a stop bit is also just a forced idle to detect the next start bit, if this is what you meant).

I was confused with the SAML's example code that I found online (https://github.com/Microchip-MPLAB-Harmony/csp_apps_sam_l22/tree/master)
However, I have figured it out. This is what I am doing now: 1. Fill the local array (app layer) which I need to transmit and generate the tx interrupt. The TX Interrupt handler will call the TX ISR which will transmit the data. Once the transmission is over, disable the tx and tx interrupt. Thanks a lot for the help everyone!

@missedSemiColon You might not want to disable the transmitter. You can do so if you need or want it, but you have to be absolutely clear what happens on the IO pin when you disable the TX, and if that is OK to your hardware. For example, does the pin change to input or go low when you disable the TX.

How do I know if I need to disable the transmitter or not? For example in a half-duplex communication (like RS485 over MODBUS), it becomes a necessity to disable the Transmitter and there is a reason for that (half-duplex comm). However, my current code does not have such requirement. So how can I confirm if I need to disable the transmitter? Please note that the current MCU's TX is connected to another MCU's RX, as I am working on an inter micro communication.

@missedSemiColon That works on another level. Disabling UART TX disables the transmit pin on the MCU. That is irrelevant if you use a RS-485 transceiver IC, you need to control if that IC is in transmit mode or receive mode, and you still have separate TX and RX pins between MCU and PHY, and you should not disable the TX output from MCU as you can't have inputs that are not driven by an output. Same for TX output to another MCU RX.

In my case, I should disable the transmitter as it is connected to the RX of another MCU. On a different note, is it a good practice to write the code to disable the transmitter and clear it's interrupt in the TX's ISR? The way I am doing it is, I am checking if all the bytes have been transmitted. If they have been transmitted, I go into an else block and call the function to disable the transmitter and clear the TX Interrupt.

@missedSemiColon Just like your MCU is not prepared for the RX pin to start floating with high impedance, likely the other MCU also does not expect you to turn off the TX pin either. And yes, there's multiple ways to do it, if you know you are transmitting the last byte, you can disable further TX interrupts, or you can check on the next interrupt that last byte was sent and there is nothing to send so TX interrupts can be disabled.
